# when i call d3.behavior.zoom my graph range.domain() becomes empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have 1 **graph** with may curves with same X scale (time)

```
ths.xRange = d3.time.scale().range([0, ths._innerWidth()]);
ths.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(ths.xRange).orient("bottom");
ths.curves = [];
```

each **curve** is child of **graph**

```
function curve(parent, init) {
    var ths = this;
    ths.parent = parent;
    ths.yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([ths.parent._innerHeight(), 0]);
    ths.xDomain = ths.parent.xRange.domain(d3.extent(ths.data.initial.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
    ths.yDomain = ths.yRange.domain(d3.extent(ths.data.initial.map(function(d) { return d.val; })));
    // line generator
    ths.line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d) { return ths.xDomain(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return ths.yDomain(d.val); });
```

but when i use zoom :

```
    ths._Sensitive.call(
            ths.CurrentZoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(ths.xRange)
            .scaleExtent([1,1000])
            .on("zoom", function() {
                window.clearTimeout(ths.timeoutID);
                ths.timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log('event <Improove granularity>');
                },
                400); // Delay (in ms) before request new data
                ths.zoom ();
            }
        )
    );
    ths.zoom = function(){
        console.log ('ths.xRange.domain()=', ths.xRange.domain());
        // trace l'axe X
        ths.svg().select("#xAxis").call(ths.xAxis);
    }
```

i have problem on domain()
before Zoom domain is good

```
graph.xRange.domain()
[Tue Jan 01 2013 00:32:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Wed Apr 10 2013 21:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)]
```

but after Zoom my domain() is wrong !

```
graph.xRange.domain()
[Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)]
```

i don't understand this behavior.

Comment: You haven't shown us what actually happens when you zoom. It seems like you're calling `ths.zoom()`, but you didn't give us the definition of that function.

Comment: ths.zoom() is almost empty :
it display x.domain() in console and redraw the xAxis.
i added it.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `curve()` you override `ths`. Thus, when calling `zoom()`, the `ths` used no longer has a `xAxis` value, which means you call `undefined` on `ths.svg().select("#xAxis")` having the consequence to set the domain of the axis to `empty` as it has to be an array.

The goal of overriding `this` is to be able to use it in child functions, thus you should not override it in the child function.

By the way. you should use `ths.svg.select("#xAxis")` instead of `ths.svg().select("#xAxis")` as I don't get why the `svg` variable representing the svg element should be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to time scales, if you define the zoom when domain of the timescale is not set, the invalid time behavior is observed. You can cover this up by setting the timescale on the zoom after you've set the domain on the timescale.

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
               .range([0,width]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
             .on("zoom", function(){
                 console.log("zoomed", d3.event.scale);
             });

xScale.domain([new Date('2014-03-15'), new Date('2014-03-30')]);

zoom.x(xScale);
```